# How can I add a google map info panel to this code with an sql database

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

guys, I can't figure out how to add an info panel to my markers in this code for each point in the database.
The info panel can basically have a random string of characters in it I just can't seem to figure out how to implement it correctly. I am new to using the google maps API and just can't figure it out, any help would be greatly accepted.
[image: Output of markers]
    `

```
          include 'connect.php';

          $apikey = "AIzaSyAobypY52GXhqSDIMPhfoojHIe7lAKJnl8";
          $id = $_GET['id'];

          $lat = 0;
          $long = 0;
          $zoom = 8;

          $findmap = "SELECT centerLat, centerLong, zoom FROM maps WHERE ID = $id";

          if(!$result = $con->query($findmap)){
             die('There was an error running the query [' . $con->error . ']');
          } else {
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            $lat = $row['centerLat'];
            $long = $row['centerLong'];
            $zoom = $row['zoom'];
          }   

        ?><!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <head>
            <meta name="viewport"
                content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
            <style type="text/css">
              html { height: 100% }
              body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
              #map-canvas { height: 100% }
            </style>
            <script type="text/javascript"
              src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=
                  <?php echo $apikey; ?>&sensor=false">
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
              function initialize() {

                var mapOptions = {
                  center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat.', '.$long; ?>),
                  zoom: <?php echo $zoom; ?>
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
                    mapOptions);
                    var markers = [];
                    var infoWindows = [];
        <?php
          $getpoints = "SELECT pointLat, pointLong, pointText 
              FROM mappoints WHERE mapID = $id";    

          if(!$result = $con->query($getpoints)){
            die('There was an error running the query 
                [' . $con->error . ']');
          } else {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              echo '  var myLatlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng('.
                  $row[pointLat].', '.$row[pointLong].');
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                  content:"'.$row[pointText].'"
                });

          var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({ 
            position: myLatlng1, 
            map: map, 
            title:"'.$row[pointText].'"
          });



          ';

            }
          }
        ?>
markers.push(marker1);
infoWindows.push(new google.maps.InfoWindow);

var i;
for(i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    infowindow[i].setContent("content for infowindow");
    infowindow[i].open(map, markers[i]);
}
              }
              google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
            </script>
          </head>
          <body>
            <a href="Addtree.php">Add A tree</a>


            <div id="map-canvas"/>

          </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: You mean `infoWindow`? Does your page show multiple markers and each of those need a `infoWindow`?

Comment: @mishka yes it will show multiple markers and each need a  info window

Comment: I would obfuscate your `$apikey` !!!

Comment: @EthanBaxter did you try what I suggested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. You could try something like this ([reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse)). This would load multiple `infoWindows` and should help you get started.

```
var map;
var markers = [];
var infoWindows = [];

/* Your map and marker creation code */

markers.push(marker1);
infoWindows.push(new google.maps.InfoWindow);

var i;
for(i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    infowindow[i].setContent("content for infowindow");
    infowindow[i].open(map, markers[i]);
}
```

**Use the code below**

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';

$apikey = "*************************";
$id = $_GET['id'];

$lat = 0;
$long = 0;
$zoom = 8;

$findmap = "SELECT centerLat, centerLong, zoom FROM maps WHERE ID = $id";

if(!$result = $con->query($findmap)){
  die('There was an error running the query [' . $con->error . ']');
} else {
  $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
  $lat = $row['centerLat'];
  $long = $row['centerLong'];
  $zoom = $row['zoom'];
}   

?>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <head>
            <meta name="viewport"
                content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
            <style type="text/css">
              html { height: 100% }
              body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
              #map-canvas { height: 100% }
            </style>
            <script type="text/javascript"
              src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=
                  <?php echo $apikey; ?>&sensor=false">
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
              var markers = [];
              var infoWindows = [];
              var map;

              function initialize() {

                var mapOptions = {
                  center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat.', '.$long; ?>),
                  zoom: <?php echo $zoom; ?>
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
                    mapOptions);

        <?php
          $getpoints = "SELECT pointLat, pointLong, pointText 
              FROM mappoints WHERE mapID = $id";    

          if(!$result = $con->query($getpoints)){
            die('There was an error running the query 
                [' . $con->error . ']');
          } else {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>
          var myLatlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $row['pointLat'] ?>, <?php echo $row['pointLong'] ?>);
          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

          var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({ 
            position: myLatlng1, 
            map: map, 
            title: "<?php echo $row['pointText']; ?>",
          });

          markers.push(marker1);
          infoWindows.push(infowindow);
      <?php
            }
          }
      ?>

var i;
for(i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    infowindow[i].setContent(markers[i].getTitle());
    infowindow[i].open(map, markers[i]);
}
              }
              google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
            </script>
          </head>
          <body>
            <a href="Addtree.php">Add A tree</a>


            <div id="map-canvas"/>

          </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: I have just attempted to add it and it is no longer displaying the map so I am guessing there is an error or I put it in the wrong spot. I have updated the above code with the changes

Comment: the map loads now but there is no info windows.

Comment: @EthanBaxter Check now. I pushed `infoWindows.push(new google.maps.InfoWindow);` up. Also, please share your new code. 
If it's possible, paste the HTML source after the page renders `Page Source`.

Comment: The code has been updated so you can look and see if I haveit in the right place or if I have it in the wrong location.

Comment: I added a picture with the map displaying multiple points but no info windows.

Comment: it is giving a console error of                                            
          map.php?id=1:55 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setContent' of undefined
    at initialize (map.php?id=1:55)

Comment: @EthanBaxter check the code in answer, update your code.

Comment: thanks your previous code did basically exactly what I wanted so I got it to work.

Comment: Great. Have fun.